# C# Dice Game (Windows Application Form) Multiple Issues

Tags: c#, windows, dice

Okay, so I'm having a number of issue with a tutorial question I'm working though so was hoping to get a bit of guidance as I'm very new to C# and not very good at it.

The scenario is this:
Write a program that simulates the rolling of two dice 1000 times. The program should count the number of double sixes rolled and also output the average score of the 1000 dice rolls. You do not need to display the results of each of the 1000 rolls and need only hit the “Run Simulation” button once per 100 rolls. The button and output should be suitably labelled.

Although the scenario says to roll 1000 times and also to roll 2 dice at one, at present, I'm only doing it 10 times and one dice roll until I can get it that bit right. Here is the code I've written so far:

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.ComponentModel;
            using System.Data;
            using System.Drawing;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;
            using System.Windows.Forms;

            namespace Dice_Roll_2___Advanced
            {
                public partial class Form1 : Form
                {
                    int roll;


                    int countDouble;
                    int countRoll;

                    int count;
                    int count2;

                    int average;
                    int doubleSix;


                    public Form1()
                    {
                        InitializeComponent();
                    }

                    private void Dice_Roll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        Random rnd = new Random();
                        for(count = 0; count <1; count++)
                        {
                            for(count2 = 0; count2 < 10; count2++)
                            {
                               roll = rnd.Next (6) + 1;
                               MessageBox.Show(roll.ToString());
                                if(roll < 6)
                                {
                                    countRoll++;
                                }
                                else if(roll == 6)
                                {
                                    countDouble++;
                                }

                            }
                        }





                    }

                    private void Average_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        average = (countRoll / 10);
                        Average.Text = average.ToString();
                    }

                    private void Doubles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        doubleSix = countDouble;
                        Doubles.Text = doubleSix.ToString();

                     }
```

Issue No.1

In the scenario, it says I have to output 100 numbers at once. As I'm only doing 10 at the moment, I wish to output 10 all at once. At present, that isn't happening. It gives me one number, I then click Ok, then it gives me the next number and so on. I believe this line in the code is the problem but not sure how to correct it.

MessageBox.Show(roll.ToString());

Issue No.2

The average does not work at all, it gives me a value of 0 every time. In my code you will see if wrote:

```
                                if(roll < 6)
                                {
                                    countRoll++;
                                }
                                else if(roll == 6)
                                {
                                    countDouble++;
                                }
```

then in the Label I wish to send the information:
average = (countRoll / 10);
                            Average.Text = average.ToString();

I know it's a lot of info but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Average = Total/count. You are not counting the SUM of rolls but diving the number of runs by 10. Since number of runs will never cross 10 (it is 0 to 9) you end up with 9/10 = 0 (WHY? think about it). What you should do is Sum = Sum + roll. and avg = sum/10

Comment: So I've now entered sum = sum +  roll;      average = sum / 10     Average.Text = average.ToString();       It's still giving me a value of 0 when I run the program. Any ideas why?

Comment: I've managed to sort the issue out with displaying the average, now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few pieces of advice:

- You can get rid of the outer loop that only runs once; it is unnecessary (the inner loop is going to run at least once already).
- Typically the declaration of the `Random` object is done at the class-level instead of in the `Click` event handler of a button. Think about it this way: with your code the way it is now, the computer has to re-create the `Random` object every time the user presses the `Dice_Roll` button. This is a waste of system resources.
- If you want to display the rolls in a single message box, you'll have to store the rolls somewhere (like an `int[]` or a `List<int>`). Then, outside the loop that performs the rolls, make another loop that will build up the message you want to show.
- Each die should be rolled once. In your current code, you are only rolling one die (and only checking if that one die was a 6).
- You should probably turn that `10` "magic number" into a constant (something like `private const int numRolls = 10;`).
- `average = (countRoll / 10);` makes no sense. You are dividing the number of rolls by 10 (which in this case...is the number of rolls). For an average, you need to add each roll up to get a total and then divide by the number of rolls.
- Your `if` statements need some tweaking too. Currently the roll is only counted if it is `< 6` meaning that a roll of `6` wont be counted, and will be left out of the average (probably not the behavior desired). `countRoll` should be incremented every time a roll is made regardless of the value of the roll.

Unfortunately this is all the feedback I have time to provide. Please don't feel like I'm trying to rip your code apart, I just wanted to point out some things that should get you back on track and clean up you code/logic a bit.

Best of luck.

Comment: No, it's all good. This is only my 2nd day of doing C# so I know I'm going to be making loads of mistakes. I've done a bit of C++ in the past but I wasn't the best at that, either. I will look over your suggestions tomorrow ans get back to you if I have any further issues, if that's okay.

Comment: Absolutely. Best of luck.